# How To upload file using Angularjs And codeigniter?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

Here is my angularjs code:
In Controller:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
    $scope.getTheFiles = function ($files) {
        console.log($files);
        angular.forEach($files, function (value, key) {
            formdata.append(key, value);
        });
    };
    // NOW UPLOAD THE FILES.
    $scope.uploadFiles = function () {

        var request = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'server/appointments/uploadedFiles',
            data: formdata,

            headers: {
                'X-API-KEY': $rootScope.currentUser.key,
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        };

        // SEND THE FILES.
        $http(request)
            .success(function (d) {
                console.log(d);
            })
            .error(function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }
}
```

And In Directive:

```
.directive('ngFiles', ['$parse', function ($parse) {

        function fn_link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var onChange = $parse(attrs.ngFiles);
            element.on('change', function (event) {
                onChange(scope, { $files: event.target.files });
            });
        };

        return {
            link: fn_link
        }
    } ]);
```

For API i use codeigniter:

```
function uploadedFiles_POST()
{
    function do_upload()
    {
        if ($this->input->post('Upload')) {
            $config['upload_path'] = './Appointments/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '1024';
            $config['max_width'] = '1024';
            $config['max_height'] = '768';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            } else {
                $data = $this->upload->data();

                $file = array(
                    'img_name' => $data['raw_name'],
                    'ext' => $data['file_ext'],
                    'upload_date' => time()
                );
                $this->appointments_model->add_image($file);
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            }
        } else {
            redirect(site_url('upload'));
        }
    }
}
```

And in codeigniter model:

```
function add_image($data)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', '395');
        return $this->db->update('user_appoint', $data);
    }
```

My problem is browser detect file name in developer tool but file cant upload to database. it show 500 status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use angular file upload down load it from here :

https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

Use this controller:

```
app.controller('FileUploadCtrl', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function($scope, FileUploader) 
{
    var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: 'Your Api path',
        autoUpload: true,
    });

    // FILTERS

    uploader.filters.push({
        name: 'customFilter',
        fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
            return this.queue.length < 10;
        }
    });

    // CALLBACKS

    uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, filter, options) {
        console.info('onWhenAddingFileFailed', item, filter, options);
    };
    uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function(fileItem) {
        console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem);
    };
    uploader.onAfterAddingAll = function(addedFileItems) {
        console.info('onAfterAddingAll', addedFileItems);
    };
    uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function(item) {
        console.info('onBeforeUploadItem', item);
    };
    uploader.onProgressItem = function(fileItem, progress) {
        console.info('onProgressItem', fileItem, progress);
    };
    uploader.onProgressAll = function(progress) {
        console.info('onProgressAll', progress);
    };
    uploader.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onSuccessItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        $('.alert').addClass('hide');
        if(response.error) {
          $('.alert-danger').html(response.message).removeClass('hide');
        } else {
          $scope.user.newimg = response.newfilename;
        }
    };
    uploader.onErrorItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onErrorItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCancelItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCancelItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCompleteAll = function() {
        console.info('onCompleteAll');
    };

    console.info('uploader', uploader);
}]);
```

View should be like this:

```
<div ng-controller="FileUploadCtrl">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Image</label>
<input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" /> 
</div>                     
</div>
```

And your Api method should be like this:

```
public function user_image_upload()
{

    $json = array();

    $config['upload_path']          = 'assets/avatar/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['encrypt_name']                 = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file') )
    {
        $json = array('error' => true, 'message' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }
    else
    {
        $upload_details = $this->upload->data();

        $json = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'File transfer completed', 'newfilename' => $upload_details['file_name']);
    }

    $this->json($json);
}
```

hopefully it will help you.

Comment: How to use those angular file and where to put.

Comment: add it on your angular route script...r u using angular route??

Comment: Yes i am using angular route, but still i have not idea where to put those file in my project and how it will accessible.

Comment: Suppose your route is this: 

.state('app.user.list', {
 url: '/list',
 templateUrl: 'user.tpl',
})

than use this as:

.state('app.user.list', {
 url: '/list',
 templateUrl: 'user.tpl',
 resolve: load( ['filepath/angular-file-upload.js'] )
})

Comment: If you are still facing problem than include it in header

Comment: what path should i provide in url for request. whether i  include post or not or else 'server/..../user_image_upload' something like that (As per your example), cuz i have to update to specific record by showing file name of uploaded file in table. And thanks for responding.

Comment: provide your method path. 
suppose your method is in api controller than just use : exaple.com/api/method_name thats it and you do not need to include post you just use this code what i gave you.

Comment: if still facing any problem than let me know.

Comment: can you give me complete idea for codeigniter code. i mean what to put in controller folder or model. cuz if i put your code in controller i receive MX_controller error.

Comment: Which code u r using into controller. See in this when you select any file that file automatically uploaded to the give directory(whatever you assigned) than in js controller method "uploader.onSuccessItem" you got the file name this file name you can save into database

Comment: in fileupload folder of controller folder i create php file of fileupload.php in that i create class fileupload extends MX_Controller then rest of your code. now i receive CI_ phpmailer error. and url i gives is 'server/fileupload/user_image_upload'.

Comment: <?php

class fileupload extends MX_Controller{


 
 function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model("fileupload_model");
  $this->load->module("upload");
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'html'));


 }

 public function user_image_upload()
 {
  $json = array();
  $config['upload_path']          = './fileupload/';
  $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
  $config['encrypt_name']                 = TRUE;}
?>       Rest of as it is.

Comment: your file upload path seems to be wrong please check it. and do not forget to include  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/ey4e/fileupload.php                                                                  here its complete file.

Comment: which file link you give me

Comment: its my controller code file where i put your code .

Comment: Use CI_Controller instead of MX_Controller and use this $config['upload_path']          = 'fileupload/'; instead of $config['upload_path']          = './fileupload/'; and make sure in you root directory there is a folder name "fileupload"

Comment: now i get error  Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class CI in path.........................\third_party\MX\Base.php  and i cannot modify core file cuz i work on big project.

Comment: ok i think you are using HMVC than just change MX_Controller instead of CI_Controller. try it

Comment: no need to hurry for today if you get time then respond me tomorrow as well. Thanks for helping to try to solve my problem .